# Why can't I use a variable in place of a string for an argument

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this work:

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST2 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = TEST1, NEWNAME = TEST2, FILENAME = 'C:\Data\TEST2')
```

But this not work:

```
DECLARE @PATH NVARCHAR(255)
SET     @PATH = 'C:\Data\TEST2'
ALTER DATABASE TEST2 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = TEST1, NEWNAME = TEST2, FILENAME = @PATH)
```

I get the error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '@PATH'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because of `ALTER` specifics, and when you are specifying a value explicitly it would be a constant, in case of variable - value will be resolved in run time.

Anyway you can pass a custom variable value using Dynamic Sql:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(128)
DECLARE @query varchar(255)
SET @name = '...'
SET @query = 'ALTER DATABASE TEST2 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = TEST1, NEWNAME = TEST2, FILENAME =  ' 
             + @name 
             + ')'
EXEC(@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

from ["ALTER DATABASE File and Filegroup Options"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx) on MSDN:

```
<filespec>::= 
(
    NAME = logical_file_name  
    [ , NEWNAME = new_logical_name ] 
    [ , FILENAME = {'os_file_name' | 'filestream_path' } ] 
    [ , SIZE = size [ KB | MB | GB | TB ] ] 
    [ , MAXSIZE = { max_size [ KB | MB | GB | TB ] | UNLIMITED } ] 
    [ , FILEGROWTH = growth_increment [ KB | MB | GB | TB| % ] ] 
    [ , OFFLINE ]
)
```

You'll note that `FILENAME` is explicitly listed as being something that starts and ends with a `'` quote mark. So, only literal strings are supported here.

That's the unsatisfactory answer - it doesn't give the underlying reason - but since I don't work for MS, I can't give a deeper answer. I'd suspect it's related to a lot of cruft in the T-SQL syntax, and the parser still being a remarkably simple/stupid one that they don't want to modify too much (except for adding new features).